# What is a resource to understand what selector patterns mean, in what direction to read them?

Tags: css-selectors, html-table

Assignment was to horizontally center (table) text in the 2nd an 3rd cells only of each row.

This worked for 3rd cells:

```
td:last-child {
    text-align: center;
}
```

However, I did the following for the middle cell, but didn't work.

```
td:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Your title is completely different (and off-topic) to your actual question.

Answer (score 0):

With the exception of the missing } after `td:last-child{ text-align: center;`

I can't see anything wrong and it works fine. maybe an error in the table html structure?

WORKING DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/yj5jbyv0/

also just for dryer css:

```
td:last-child,
td:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: center; 
}
```